# java cant find or load my program when I have a package heading

Tags: java, cmd, classpath

I can run programs which do not have a package without any hitch. If I try and add a package then java simply cannot find them. I have set the class path and I have tried running - java packagename.ProgramName.

I have found a number of similar threads on here and have spent four hours going through all of them and trying everything and nothing works for me.

Yet as soon as I edit the .java file and recompile without a package heading - it immediately works perfectly. Why? And how can I fix it? I would like to be able to have my classes organised in packages!

This is the code I am using (I normally use eclipse and just wrote this to try out cmd out of curiosity).

```
package hello;
public class HelloWorldApp{

    public static void helloWorld(){
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

and

```
package hello;
public class HelloBackApp{

    public static void helloBack(){
        System.out.println("Hello back");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        HelloWorldApp.helloWorld();
        helloBack();
    }
}
```

As I say if I delete both the package heading java HelloBackApp runs just fine.

And my path to my program is

c:\Users\sam\javastuff\hello

I have of course tried java hello.HelloBackApp from both the javastuff dir and the hello dir. No joy

It works immediately if I delete both the package headings and type java HelloBackApp from the hello directory.

Comment: You have `package packageName;` in the top of your java file, yeah?

Comment: Show your code with package and your class path

Comment: Sanjeev I have editted my original comment hopefully with a bit more thorough information. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after much research I realised what my problem was and have fully resolved it. I think I see why I have been unable to find an "answer" to this question in forums. It is not a simple quick fix - my whole understanding of how to correctly get the class path set up and get a proper compile done was very poor. It becomes a whole new subject if you switch from compiling/running on an IDE to doing so from the command line. I think it is an excellent thing for new programmers to do though as I believe the improved understanding of CLASSPATH is going to be something that will stand us all in good stead for the future.

I found all the answers to my questions here :  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-classpath-windows/

and recommend anyone having similar problems I was having to read through this excellent document. Best wishes to all the other guys struggling with this out there! :)

Answer (score 0):

try as follows,
create folder structure as your package and place java file in that folder 
For ex, my java file is under 
    c:\code\com\test\Test.java and package is "package com.test".
I compiled and run code from 
   `c:\code>`
   `c:\code> javac com\test\Test.java`
   `c:\code> java com.test.Test`

Comment: my current path structure is c:\Users\sam\javastuff\hello

Comment: and I am running from the hello folder although I have tried java hello.HelloBackApp both from the hello folder and the main folder java stuff as well